# Set fields in an array of sub documents in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have an environment document which has quotes field which is an array in which i need to update. Tried using the below query in node. The query fails at the set commands. I tried using it only with find, which returned the environment object.

```
Environments.
findOneAndUpdate({query,
                      $set:
                              {
                                'xpaths.$.work': work,
                                'xpaths.$.update': update
                              }
                      }).exec(function(err, env){
                        if (err) {
                          console.log("Error finding report");
                        } else if(env) {
                          console.log("Env not found in database", env);
                        }
                      });
```

Comment: Bracket in the wrong place: `findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: { 'xpaths.$.work': work,  'xpaths.$.update': update  }},{ new: true })`. And you are also missing `new: true` to return the modified document. Beyond that, show us what is in `query` as well in your question. But it looks like typos and missing options.

Comment: @NeilLunn-Thanks!